# What's the difference between multiple parameters lists and multiple parameters per list in Scala?

Tags: scala, currying, partial-application

In Scala one can write (curried?) functions like this

```
def curriedFunc(arg1: Int) (arg2: String) = { ... }
```

What is the difference between the above `curriedFunc` function definition with two parameters lists and functions with multiple parameters in a single parameter list:

```
def curriedFunc(arg1: Int, arg2: String) = { ... }
```

From a mathematical point of view this is `(curriedFunc(x))(y)` and `curriedFunc(x,y)` but I can write `def sum(x) (y) = x + y` and the same will be `def sum2(x, y) = x + y`

I know only one difference - this is partially applied functions. But both ways are equivalent for me.

Are there any other differences?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is not a curried function, but a method with multiple argument lists, although admittedly it looks like a function.

As you said, the multiple arguments lists allow the method to be used in the place of a partially applied function. (Sorry for the generally silly examples I use)

```
object NonCurr {
  def tabulate[A](n: Int, fun: Int => A) = IndexedSeq.tabulate(n)(fun)
}

NonCurr.tabulate[Double](10, _)            // not possible
val x = IndexedSeq.tabulate[Double](10) _  // possible. x is Function1 now
x(math.exp(_))                             // complete the application
```

Another benefit is that you can use curly braces instead of parenthesis which looks nice if the second argument list consists of a single function, or thunk. E.g.

```
NonCurr.tabulate(10, { i => val j = util.Random.nextInt(i + 1); i - i % 2 })
```

versus

```
IndexedSeq.tabulate(10) { i =>
  val j = util.Random.nextInt(i + 1)
  i - i % 2
}
```

Or for the thunk:

```
IndexedSeq.fill(10) {
  println("debug: operating the random number generator")
  util.Random.nextInt(99)
}
```

Another advantage is, you can refer to arguments of a previous argument list for defining default argument values (although you could also say it's a disadvantage that you cannot do that in single list :)

```
// again I'm not very creative with the example, so forgive me
def doSomething(f: java.io.File)(modDate: Long = f.lastModified) = ???
```

Finally, there are three other application in an answer to related post [Why does Scala provide both multiple parameters lists and multiple parameters per list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684185/why-does-scala-provide-both-multiple-parameters-lists-and-multiple-parameters-per) . I will just copy them here, but the credit goes to Knut Arne Vedaa, Kevin Wright, and extempore.

First: you can have multiple var args:

```
def foo(as: Int*)(bs: Int*)(cs: Int*) = as.sum * bs.sum * cs.sum
```

...which would not be possible in a single argument list.

Second, it aids the type inference:

```
def foo[T](a: T, b: T)(op: (T,T) => T) = op(a, b)
foo(1, 2){_ + _}   // compiler can infer the type of the op function

def foo2[T](a: T, b: T, op: (T,T) => T) = op(a, b)
foo2(1, 2, _ + _)  // compiler too stupid, unfortunately
```

And last, this is the only way you can have implicit and non implicit args, as `implicit` is a modifier for a whole argument list:

```
def gaga [A](x: A)(implicit mf: Manifest[A]) = ???   // ok
def gaga2[A](x: A, implicit mf: Manifest[A]) = ???   // not possible
```

Comment: Since it's the most voted answer I think the question's title does no longer correspond to its answer. I think the title should be changed to, say, "Why does Scala provide both multiple parameters lists and multiple parameters per list?", i.e. it's already merged by the samples with with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684185/why-does-scala-provide-both-multiple-parameters-lists-and-multiple-parameters-pe.

Answer (score 42):

There's another difference that was not covered by 0__'s excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803211/scala-curried-function/6803909#6803909): default parameters. A parameter from one parameter list can be used when computing the default in another parameter list, but not in the same one.

For example:

```
def f(x: Int, y: Int = x * 2) = x + y // not valid
def g(x: Int)(y: Int = x * 2) = x + y // valid
```

Comment: Took this simple example for this to sink in. That actually makes default parameters much more useful. Thanks!

Comment: Good example, except I spent five minutes to figure out how to call it:
`g(1)()` returns 3.

`g(1)(2)` returns 5.

Answer (score 20):

That's the whole point, is that the curried and uncurried forms are equivalent! As others have pointed out, one or the other form can be *syntactically* more convenient to work with depending on the situation, and that is the only reason to prefer one over the other.

It's important to understand that even if Scala didn't have special syntax for declaring curried functions, you could still construct them; this is just a mathematical inevitability once you have the ability to create functions which return functions.

To demonstrate this, imagine that the `def foo(a)(b)(c) = {...}` syntax didn't exist. Then you could still achieve the exact same thing like so: `def foo(a) = (b) => (c) => {...}`.

Like many features in Scala, this is just a syntactic convenience for doing something that would be possible anyway, but with slightly more verbosity.

Answer (score 4):

The two forms are isomorphic. The main difference is that curried functions are easier to apply partially, while non-curried functions have slightly nicer syntax, at least in Scala.

Comment: Hasn't it been earlier said the examples are *not* curried functions? I understand a curried function has only a single argument and may return a function with a single argument and so on until there's a body with all the arguments closed over. Am I wrong?