# Play 2.0 re-usable template function with HTML body

Tags: function, templates, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to get my head around this concept, but the power of functional programming is yet weak in me, so I can't immediately get to grips with it. What I would like to do is define a re-usable template function with *some* parameters but an `Html` body *as well*.

For example, consider the following re-usable function in a template:

```
@myFunction(label: String, labelTarget: String, content: Html) = {
    <label for="@labelTarget">@label</label>
    <div>@content</div>
}
```

I would then like to use this function as follows:

```
...

<h2>My function content below!</h2>
@myFunction("label", "target") {
    <span>My additional content used by the function</span>
}

...
```

I get a feeling this should be doable, but can't seem to figure it out. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only mistake you made is that you haven't defined your content as a new block of parameters :

```
@myFunction(label: String, labelTarget: String)(content: Html) = {
    <label for="@labelTarget">@label</label>
    <div>@content</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I shall have to try this out when I get home. Could you perhaps provide a little more insight in how this works?

Comment: Having a looksy myself, these are apparently functions with [multiple parameter lists](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#multiple_parameter_lists), which is sometimes confused with [function currying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803211/what-is-a-curried-function-in-scala). I somehow managed to miss the multiple parameter lists bit so far :-)