# Too many arguments when I use (...)(...) function

Tags: scala

I am on my way to learning Scala after coming from different programming languages (mostly interpreted). I am doing the following exercise and I get an error.

```
def sum(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    def loop(a: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
      if (a >= b) acc
      else loop(a+1, f(a) + acc)
    }
    loop(a, 0)
 }
 sum(x => x * x, 2, 4) //Too many arguments
```

I can't see what is wrong there?

Answer (score 5):

If you declare your function with multiple parentheses (multiple argument lists), you also have to call it like that (curried form):

```
sum(x => x * x)(2, 4)
```

See [What's the difference between multiple parameters lists and multiple parameters per list in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6803211/1374678) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The function must be called in the explicitly curried form (there must be a better name) because that is how it is defined:

```
sum(x => x * x)(2, 4)

//def sum (f: Int => Int) (a: Int, b: Int):
//    sum (x => x * x)    (2,      4)
```

But this is also neat, because only one part of the curried form must be evaluated at a time:

```
val sumOfSquares = sum(x => x * x)
val s = someOfSquares(2,4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `sum` with [two parameter lists](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#multiple_parameter_lists) but are trying to call it with just one.

The syntactically correct way to call it would be `sum(x => x * x)(2, 4)`