# Scala: Is operator foldl infix?

Tags: scala, fold

Looking at code with `foldl` it is hard to understand its syntax, for example:

```
  def lstToMap(lst:List[(String,Int)], map: Map[String, Int] ):Map[String, Int] = {
    (map /: lst) (addToMap)
  }
```

Is `/:` infix operator?  What does `(map /: lst)` mean, partial application? Why I can not call like this:

```
`/:  map lst addToMap`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method names that end in a `:` character can be used on the left hand side of the instance they're bound to (ie, they associate to the right). In this case, `/:` is a [method on `List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List). As per the Scaladoc:

> Note: /: is alternate syntax for foldLeft; z /: xs is the same as xs foldLeft z.

An alternative to what you wrote would be:

```
lst./:(map)(addToMap)
```

Edit: and another alternative with foldLeft:

```
lst.foldLeft(map)(addToMap)
```

Comment: Kristian, @DaoWen,  As I understand `foldLeft` has two arguments - initial value and a folding function. Then why `lst.foldLeft(map, addToMap)` results in error `too many arguments for method foldLeft: (z: B)(f: (B, (String, Int)) => B)B` ?

Comment: `foldLeft` has two parameter groups (as seen by the two groups of parens) - the first group expects one argument, which is the reason for the error message. The second argument goes in the second group. I've edited the answer with an example using `foldLeft`. As you can see, it's literally a drop-in replacement for `/:`

Comment: Kristian, thanks! Where to read about Scala function parameter groups? Can't find this in the docs so far ...

Comment: It's formally defined in section 4.6 of the Scala spec (http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) and there's some more informal discussion in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803211/whats-the-difference-between-multiple-parameters-lists-and-multiple-parameters

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `/:` can be used as an infix operator. However, the *fold* operation takes **three** arguments:

1. The sequence to fold across
2. The initial value for the reduction
3. The function used for folding

Using infix you can only specify two of these three arguments: the sequence (which is the receiver) and the initial value. The fact that `(map /: lst)` is a partial application reflects the fact that you're still missing an argument. Here's an example of a product of a sequence of numbers, starting with an initial value of 1:

```
(1 /: xs)(_*_)
```

Since Scala supports curly braces for function literals, you can also use that to make the function argument look more like a function body:

```
(1 /: xs) { (x, y) =>
    x * y
}
```