# Is scala disregading type in function signatures?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am going through lectures from excellent Martin Odersky's FP course and one of the lectures demonstrates higher-order functions through Newton's method for finding fixed points of certain functions. There is a cruicial step in the lecture where I think type signature is being violated so I would ask for an explanation. (Apologies for the long intro that's inbound - it felt it was needed.)

One way of implementing such an algorithm is given like this:

```
  val tolerance = 0.0001

  def isCloseEnough(x: Double, y: Double) = abs((x - y) / x) / x < tolerance

  def fixedPoint(f: Double => Double)(firstGuess: Double) = {
    def iterate(guess: Double): Double = {
      val next = f(guess)
      if (isCloseEnough(guess, next)) next
      else iterate(next)
    }
    iterate(firstGuess)
  }
```

Next, we try to compute the square root via fixedPoint function, but the naive attempt through

```
def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint(y => x / y)(1)
```

is foiled because such an approach oscillates (so, for `sqrt(2)`, the result would alternate indefinitely between 1.0 and 2.0).

To deal with that, we introduce average damping, so that essentially we compute the mean of two nearest calculated values and converge to solution, therefore

```
def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint(y => (y + x / y) / 2)(1)
```

Finally, we introduce `averageDamp` function and the task is to write `sqrt` with `fixedPoint` and `averageDamp`.  The `averageDamp` is defined as follows:

```
def averageDamp(f: Double => Double)(x: Double) = (x + f(x)) / 2
```

Here comes the part I don't understand - my initial solution was this:

```
def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint(z => averageDamp(y => x / y)(z))(1)
```

but prof. Odersky's solution was more concise:

```
def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint(averageDamp(y => x / y))(1)
```

My question is - why does it work? According to function signature, the `fixedPoint` function is supposed to take a function (`Double => Double`) but it doesn't mind being passed an ordinary Double (which is what `averageDamp` returns - in fact, if you try to explicitly specify the return type of Double to `averageDamp`, the compiler won't throw an error).

I think that my approach follows types correctly - so what am I missing here? Where is it specified or implied(?) that `averageDamp` returns a function, especially given the right-hand side is clearly returning a scalar? How can you pass a scalar to a function that clearly expects functions only? How do you reason about code that seems to not honour type signatures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution is correct, but it can be more concise.

Let's scrutinize the `averageDamp` function more closely.

```
def averageDamp(f: Double => Double)(x: Double): Double = (x + f(x)) / 2
```

The return type annotation is added to make it more clearly. I think what you are missing is here:

> but it doesn't mind being passed an ordinary Double (which is what averageDamp returns - in fact, if you try to explicitly specify the
>   return type of Double to averageDamp, the compiler won't throw an
>   error).

But `averageDamp(y => y/x)` does return a `Double => Double` function! `averageDamp` requires to be passed **TWO** argument lists to return a `Double`.

If the function receive just one argument, it still wants the other one to be completed. So rather than returning the result immediately, it returns a function, saying that "I still need an argument here, feed me that so I will return what you want".

Prof MO did pass **ONE** function argument to it, not two, so `averageDamp` is *partially applied*, in the sense that it returns a `Double => Double` function.

The course will also tell you functions with multiple argument lists are syntactical sugar form of this:

```
def f(arg1)(arg2)(arg3)...(argN-1)(argN) = (argN) => f(arg1)(arg2)(arg3)...(argN-1)
```

If you give one less argument than f needs, it just return the right side of equation, that is, a function. So, heeding that `averageDamp(y => x / y)`, the argument passed to `fixPoint`, is actually a function should help you understand the question.

*Notice: There is some difference between partially applied function(or function currying) and multiple argument list function*

For example you cannot declare like this

```
val a = averageDamp(y => y/2)
```

The compiler will complain about this as 'method is not a partially applied function'.

The difference is explained here: [What's the difference between multiple parameters lists and multiple parameters per list in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803211/whats-the-difference-between-multiple-parameters-lists-and-multiple-parameters).

Comment: This link should help http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala

Comment: Hm, that SO thread is over my head but the other link helped a bit. So, the way I understand it (please correct me if I am wrong) is that currying is essentially a deferred function call - deferred until all f-args are satisfied (closed over). Until they are, the partially applied f returns as result _another_ f (call it `f'`), such that all unsatisfied args form the **left-hand** side of `f'` and the body forms the right-hand side of `f'` and is unchanged. I still have trouble understanding what's happening under the bonnet - who passes the scalar arg `x` to `averageDamp`? When?

Comment: I think you grasp the general idea of currying. And `fixPoint` pass `x` to partially applied `averageDamp`, just in the line `val next = f(guess)`

Answer (score 1):

Multiple parameter lists are syntactic sugar for a function that returns another function. You can see this in the scala shell:

```
scala> :t averageDamp _
(Double => Double) => (Double => Double)
```

We can write the same function without the syntactic sugar - this is the way we'd do it in e.g. Python:

```
def averageDamp(f: Double => Double): (Double => Double) = {
   def g(x: Double): Double = (x + f(x)) / 2
   g
}
```

Returning a function can look a bit weird to start with, but it's complementary to passing a function as an argument and enables some very powerful programming techniques. Functions are just another type of value, like `Int` or `String`.

In your original solution you were reusing the variable name `y`, which I think makes it slightly confusing; we can translate what you've written into:

```
def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint(z => averageDamp(y => x / y)(z))(1)
```

With this form, you can hopefully see the pattern:

```
def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint(z => something(z))(1)
```

And hopefully it's now obvious that this is the same as:

```
def sqrt(x: Double) = fixedPoint(something)(1)
```

which is Odersky's version.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question without reusing the variable - it confused the hell out of me but I didn't know I could just introduce a new letter just like that.