# Why does a curried constructor throw an error on partial function application?

Tags: scala, constructor, currying

when I try to create a curried constructor, like

```
class MyClass(a: Int, b: Int)(c: String) {
  // Some Implementation
}
```

why does partial application like

```
val partialConstructor = new MyClass(x, y)
```

result in the error message

```
missing argument list for constructor MyClass in class MyClass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You confuse curried functions with functions of multiple argument lists. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803909/187261) why there are function with multiple argument lists.

For your example you should explicitly say that you want a curried function

```
val partialConstructor = new MyClass(x, y)(_)
```