# What does `(...)(...)` mean in Scala code?

Tags: scala

I got this piece of code from https://index.scala-lang.org/playframework/play-json that I don't fully understand:

```scala
implicit val locationReads: Reads[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "lat").read[Double](min(-90.0) keepAnd max(90.0)) and
  (JsPath \ "long").read[Double](min(-180.0) keepAnd max(180.0))
)(Location.apply _)
```

What does `(...)(...)` mean? I took a look at the Scala syntax cheat sheet but still cannot figure what it is. Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between multiple parameters lists and multiple parameters per list in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803211/whats-the-difference-between-multiple-parameters-lists-and-multiple-parameters)

Answer (score 5):

Without syntax sugar, what you have is:

```scala
(JsPath \ "lat").read[Double](min(-90.0) keepAnd max(90.0))
 .and( (JsPath \ "long").read[Double](min(-180.0) keepAnd max(180.0)) )
 .apply(Location.apply _)
```

The parentheses around the `(... and ...)` in your post are just like the parentheses in an expression like `(1 + 2) / 3`. They were used so the `and` method could be called like an operator and then call a method on the result of that `and` method. Nothing really special there.

The parentheses around `Location.apply _` are because you are passing `Location.apply _` as an argument to a function. You are technically calling the `(... and ...)` object's `apply` method, and omitting the word "apply" thanks to a Scala syntax sugar.

In scala, objects with an `apply` method can be treated as functions thanks to the syntax sugar, i.e. the following two statements are equivalent:

```scala
foo.apply(1)
foo(1) // equivalent
```

Note that this is *not* "currying" as the other answer states.

Currying is a way to represent a function with multiple arguments as a series of "functions which return functions", e.g.

```scala
def myFunc(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = a + b + c

val sum = myFunc(1, 2, 3)

def myCurriedFunc(a: Int)(b: Int)(c: Int) = a + b + c
val sum = myCurriedFunc(1)(2)(3)
val addOneAndTwo = myCurriedFunc(1)(2)
val sumAgain = addOneAndTwo(3)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is called currying, and it means that the function returns another function that takes one argument.

Comment: What function returns another function?