# Syntax: Function after its parameter takes another enclosed parameter

Tags: scala, syntax

I am new to Scala and I saw following code snipplet, which I do not understand at all.

```
 myFunction(param)(request)
```

What is (request) doing in the above code? Its obviously not a parameter.

I have been googling for 2 hours to find out what this means but I don't even understand what to google. Forgive me for such a basic question but I have no idea.

Comment: But you definitely do not need that Java tag here.

Comment: And I think you find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684185/why-does-scala-provide-both-multiple-parameters-lists-and-multiple-parameters-pe (and I am not a scala person, I just asked google for "scala methods double params" ;-)